# A proof of root of unity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots-of-unity

Let $\omega$ be the root of unity $e^{2\pi i/90}$, prove that
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{45}\sin(2n^\circ)=\sum_{n=1}^{45}\frac{\omega^n-1}{2i\omega^{n/2}}.
$$

Comment: This seems incorrect: $\omega^{n/2} - \omega^{-n/2} = 2 i \sin (n \pi /90) = 2 i \sin (2n^\circ)$

$$ RHS = \sum_1^{45} \sin (2n^\circ) > 1 > \prod_1^{45} \sin (2n^\circ) = LHS$$

Comment: The original problem is here: http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h425751p2409488                     I'm asking about a step of the official solution of Algebra A7 in PUMaC 2010. I cannot understand how they get that equation in my post.

Comment: Consider that $\sum_n \sin n x=  \sum_n  Im (e^{i x n})=Im \sum_n (e^{i x n})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link provided to AOPS solution Method 2, the summation sign should be a product sign instead. This gives:

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{n=1}^{45}\sin(2n^\circ)&=\prod_{n=1}^{45}\sin \frac{n\pi}{90}\\
&=\prod_{n=1}^{45}\frac{e^{in\pi/90}-e^{-in\pi/90}}{2i}\\
&=\prod_{n=1}^{45}\frac{\omega^{n/2}-\omega^{-n/2}}{2i}\\
&=\prod_{n=1}^{45}\frac{\omega^n-1}{2i\omega^{n/2}}\qquad\text{(=RHS)}
\end{align}$$

Completing the proof, according to Method 2, but correcting the summation symbol:
$$\begin{align}
\prod_{n=1}^{45}\sin(2n^\circ)=\prod_{n=1}^{44}\sin(2n^\circ)=\prod_{n=46}^{89}\sin(2n^\circ)
\end{align}$$
by symmetry of $\sin$ around $90^\circ$ and also noting that $\sin 90^\circ=1$. Hence

$$\begin{align}
\left[\prod_{n=1}^{45}\sin(2n^\circ)\right]^2&=\prod_{n=1}^{45}\sin(2n^\circ)\prod_{n=46}^{89}\sin(2n^\circ)\\
&=\prod_{n=1}^{89}\sin(2n^\circ)\\
&=\prod_{n=1}^{89}\frac{\omega^n-1}{2i\omega^{n/2}}\\
&=\prod_{n=1}^{89}\frac{\bigl|\omega^n-1\bigr|}2\bigg/\underbrace{\prod_{n=1}^{89}\bigl|i\omega^{-n/2}\bigr|}_{=1}\\
&=\prod_{n=1}^{89}\frac{\bigl|\omega^n-1\bigr|}2\\
&=\frac{90}{2^{89}}\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{as $\small{\prod_{n=1}^{89}\bigl|\omega^n-1\bigr|=90}$}\\
&=\frac{45}{2^{88}}\\
\prod_{n=1}^{45}\sin(2n^\circ)&=\frac{3\sqrt{5}}{2^{44}}=\frac{
\overbrace{3\cdot 2^6}^p\sqrt5}{2^{50}}\\
p&=192
\end{align}$$

Comment: How is $\small{\prod_{n=1}^{89}\bigl|\omega^n-1\bigr|=90}$?                              @hypergeometric

Comment: If $\omega=\exp\left(i2\pi/m\right)$ is the primitive $m$-th root of unity, then $\prod_{n=1}^{m-1}\bigl|\omega^n-1\bigr|=m$.

Comment: What is this theorem? @hypergeometric

Comment: As defined, $\omega^n$  are roots of $z^{m}-1=0$ or $(z-1)(z^{m-1}+z^{m-2}+\cdots+z+1)=0$. Hence $(\omega_n-1)$ must be roods of $(z+1)^{m-1}+(z+1)^{m-2}+\cdots+(z+1)+1=0$ or $z^{m-1}+\cdots +m=0$. By Vieta's formula, product of roots is given by $\prod_{n=1}^{m-1}(\omega^n-1)=(-1)^{m-1}m$. Hence $\prod_{n=1}^{m-1}\bigl| \omega^n-1 \bigr|=m$.

Comment: To clarify further the comment above: in general, if $\omega^n$ is a root, then $\omega^{-n}$ is also a root. It can easily be shown that $(\omega^n-1),(\omega^{-n}-1)$ are complex conjugates. Hence $(\omega^n-1)(\omega^{-n}-1)=\bigl|\omega^n-1\bigr| \bigl|\omega^{-n}-1\bigr|$. If $m$ is odd, then $\omega^n=-1$ is a root, and has no conjugate; for this $n$, magnitude scales by $\bigl|\omega^n-1\bigr|$ when multiplied by $(\omega^n-1)$. Hence $\prod_{n=1}^{m-1}(\omega^n-1)=(-1)^{m-1}m$ implies $\prod_{n=1}^{m-1}\bigl|\omega^n-1\bigr|=m$.